# Is normal PVC tubing okay for a racking tube?

Tags: equipment

I'm having a few issues finding food-grade plastic tubing to use a racking tube.

Is normal clear PVC tubing that you'd get at a hardware store okay for this? (Once it's been sterilized etc of course)

For sterilizing these, is it okay to boil them in the microwave for a few minutes, or is the plastic too soft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PVC clear tubing I buy at the hardware store is the same spool my LHBS has. It's designed for water use.

I buy it at the LHBS to support him, but since he's 25 minutes across town, I only do that if it's convenient.

As to the tubing, don't boil it. You can't achieve sterilization anyway, from a practical standpoint.

Start with hot soapy water, get it good and clean then rinse well with hot water from the tap.

Then sanitize with your favorite no-rinse sanitizer. (One-Step, StarSan, Idophor, etc..) Remember to leave it in contact, inside and outside, for the prescribed time based on the sanitizer.  Most are 60 to 120 seconds.

Good luck!

Comment: You are very welcome.